# Can't run CnCNet for Red Alert 2 Yuri's Revenge, Linux Multiplayer?

Tags: linux, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I really want to play with my friend RA2 YR multiplayer in Linux, I can't seem to be able to run CnCNet. Mono does not work as clientogl.exe does not exist. I tried mental omega, it crashes when trying to start a game, I did what was said in https://github.com/CnCNet/xna-cncnet-client/issues/59.

Comment: You should ask about these kind of issues on the forum of cncnet; the devs are much more likely to see your question there.